# swift resolving variable in generic type constrained array parameter

Tags: ios, swift, generics, equatable

Given

```
class MyClass {
    static let Anything = 1

    func wasCalled<T:AnyObject where T:Equatable>(values: [T]) { }
}
```

why does this compile:

```
MyClass().wasCalled([1, "a string"])
```

but this produces "cannot invoke 'wasCalled' with an argument list of type '(NSArray)'"

```
MyClass().wasCalled([MyClass.Anything, "a string"])
```

as does

```
let n = 2
MyClass().wasCalled([n, "a string"])
```

using: Xcode 7 beta 6, Swift 2

Comment: `1` doesn't have type, but `Anything` and `n` have type of `Int`

Comment: Looks like a candidate for RADAR?

Comment: would '1' not be inferred as type Int? Besides, Int still satisfies T expectations, so why can't the compiler resolve it as [T], not NSArray?

Comment: Because `MyClass.Anything` is an `Int`, whereas `"a string"` is a string. Hence, the typechecker is unable to deduce one unambiguous type for use with Swift's built-in array, and makes it a "one object fits all" `NSArray` instead (since it's inherently heterogeneous).

Comment: that doesn't explain why `MyClass().wasCalled([1, "a string"])` compiles